Lift morphism on pullback of modules
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, consider the short exact sequence in $R$-Mod: $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$
Given $C' \hookrightarrow C$ we can construct (using pullback) the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>>> B' @>>> C' @>>> 0\\
@V{=}VV @V{=}VV @VVV @VVV @V{=}VV\\
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> C @>>>0
\end{CD}
Since $C' \cong B'/A$ and $C \cong B/A$, I want to lift the morphism $C' \hookrightarrow C$ to a morphism in $Hom (C',B)$, is this possible or there exist a counterexample?
